# Como fazer o libreoffice interpretar o sinal de - enviado por programa em python?

Tags: python

Olá, estou tentando usar `worksheet.write_formula(row,col+5,'=B%d-E1'%(row+1))` para escrever uma formula no CALC, mas o sinal de menos parece está sendo interpretado incorretamente no Libreoffice sendo necessário que eu altere manualmente o sinal. Vocês saberiam como resolvo este problema?

O código completo é este:

```
from pyexcel_ods import save_data 
import time, sys
import xlsxwriter
import serial

receivedSF = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
row = 0
col = 0
count = input("Numero de dados a ser coletados: ")

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(0,3,"TEMPO DE REFERENCIA:")
worksheet.write(0,4,time.time())
for item in range(count):
   valor = int(receivedSF.read(2))
   print row, valor
   worksheet.write(row,col, valor)
   worksheet.write(row,col+1,time.time())
   worksheet.write_formula(row,col+5,'=B%d-E1'%(row+1))
   row+=1
workbook.close()
receivedSF.close()
```

Comment: Poderia descrever o "alterar manualmente" ?

Comment: Pode colocar as versões do xlsxwriter, libreoffice, Python que vocẽ está usando (`xlsxswriter.__version__`  contém a versão). E também qual sistema operacional?
Testei escrever uma fórmula com "-" no Linux, com Python 3.6 e xlsxwriter 0.9.8  e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Uma sugestão -use `xlsxwriter.write_formula(XXX, YYY, "=%f" % time.time() ) ` e também para o valor - em vez de `.write(...)` - a razão é que o `write` como escreve só o texto das células pode estar sujeito as diferenças entre o "." e a "," como separador para os decimais, se o seu libreoffice estiver em Português.  Com o "writeformula", o libreoffice deveria entender o conteúdo como numérico independente da formatação.

Se o problema for só esse no entanto, não deveria se corrigir com a substituição manual do "-".

Comment: JSbueno obrigado pelo retorno: as versões são Python 2.7.12; xlsxswriter 0.9.8; ubuntu 16.04 LTS. O problema não é a interpretação da "," porque quando altero o sinal "-" manualmente ele faz a operação normalmente.

Comment: Eu acho que pode ser alguma incompatibilidade com o encoding já que o linguagens de programação usam ASCII, só que não sei como verificar isto.

Comment: Fiz uma gambiarra, 'workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')' neste trecho do código é gerado um arquivo com a extensão .xlsx o que fiz foi criar uma copia deste arquivo com a extensão .ods e a planilha passou a funcionar corretamente. Mas ainda não sei como resolver o problema diretamente em python.

Comment: por qu você não está usando Python 3.6?  Python 2.7 é de 2010 - e vai sair de linha em mais 3 anos.  o Ubuntu é só instalar o pacote "python3"  chamar seu programa com "python3"  (se você não estiver usando virtualenv - o que deveria estar) . VOcê não colocou a versão do libreoffice - esquci de pedir - mas parece ser o problema Aqui é 5.2.7.2

Comment: Na verdade tenho o Python 2.7 e o 3.5 mas como estou iniciando em Python preferi usar o 2.7 que já estava no Ubuntu, já que quando escrevi o código usei algumas coisas incompatíveis com Python 3.5. E a versão do libreoffice é a 5.1.6.2.